# How to redo an file which is lost due to "undo"

Tags: windows-8.1, microsoft-word, undo

I have a file on which i was working on yesterday. After saving, I copied it to a pendrive. Then I went to the desktop and bymistakely pressed undo several times.

After a few other-file arrangements, i noticed that my original file was "undo"ed

I checked on the pen drive too. It was gone.
I used several recovery softwares on the pendrive and recovered my 2.7 MB file.

But its gibberish. I tried to repair the WORD DOCUMENT online but it gave me 7MB of gibberish data. I think the extra data was expansion of image files but i am not sure how it works.

Is there a way to decode this gibberish into text that makes sense?

Or to recover my file?

Comment: Office has his own temp folder, maybe you can take a look there... ¿Office version?

Comment: microsoft office 2007

Comment: Try Microsoft solution - [How to recover a lost file in Word 2007 or in Word 2003](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/827099)

Comment: Didnt work. could you give another solution